# unexport doesn't work on BBB GPIOs

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard, sysfs

When entering the /sys/class/gpio/ directory on a beagle bone running `Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 22 01:16:12 UTC 2018 armv7l`, already several GPIOs get displayed, without me exporting them first. Trying to unexport them by using `sudo echo gpio30 > unexport` results in `echo: write error: Invalid argument`.

1. Why are all the GPIOs already exportet on BBB?
2. Why can't I unexport them?
3. What would be the best way to control those GPIO from a C++/C program? Should I really use ofstream? Or is there a different interfacing-lib already installed on my BBB?

Comment: Check the device tree that is used by your running kernel. Most do map pins necessary for e.g. eMMC, SD-card, HDMI, I²C EEPROM, etc. Also consult the SRM as to which pins are available for what and which conflicts can arise.